# Is there an addon for automatic UV overlap?

Tags: uv, add-on

I have a model that pretty much is symmetrical in X and Y axis, I think overlap uv would be pretty smart but too much work doing it all by hand.

All solutions to uv overlap I found online are for simple models, but what if I have quite a lot of seams?Is there a way to automate it? I feel like it is really good idea for a addon, though feels like someone already thought about it.[image]

Comment: what if you split your mesh in half, delete one side, unwrap it, and add & apply a mirror modifier?

Answer (score 0):

I use UV Packmaster for this. It has an align function which will do it automatically if your UVs are identical. There are options for allignment if they're flipped or even slightly off. It has a whole lot of super useful tools built in that speed up the UV workflow by a ton.